# How can I check a string input to be a valid double?

Tags: c++, string, validation, double

Here is my code. I am creating a program that takes a string input and converts it to a double. However, I need to validate that the input was a valid double. So how would I go about this? For example, 3.14 would be valid, but things like 3.1.4, bob123, etc would not be valid.

```
namespace validInput
{
bool IsValidDouble(string inputString)
{
    int start = 0; // the index we will start looking for digits
    bool valid = true;  // assume valid for now
    int decCount = 0;

    // check for an empty string
    if (inputString.length() < 1)
    {
        valid = false; // no need to check anything else
    }        
    // next, check for a leading sign
    else if (inputString.at(0) == '-'|| inputString.at(0) == '+')
    {
        start = 1;  // start checking for digits after the sign

        // check that there's at least one character after the sign
        if (inputString.length() < 2)
        {        
        valid = false; // no need to check anything else
        }
    }
        // *****************************************
        // CHECK FOR ONLY ONE DECIMAL IN INPUT
        // *****************************************
    return valid; // return true if valid, false if not
}

// Taking string, validating, converting to float(decimal)
double TryDoubleInput()
{
    double dNumber;
    string inputString;

    //cin >> inputString;  // accept a string input
    getline(cin, inputString);
    if (!IsValidDouble(inputString)) 
    {
        cerr << "Invalid input. Please enter a number: ";
        dNumber = TryDoubleInput();
    }
    else
    {
        dNumber = atof(inputString.c_str()); // convert to an integer
    }
    return  dNumber;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `double strtod (const char* str, char** endptr)`
On success, the function returns the converted floating point number as a value of type double.
If no valid conversion could be performed, the function returns zero (0.0).
If the correct value is out of the range of representable values for the type, a positive or negative HUGE_VAL is returned, and errno is set to ERANGE.

Answer (score 0):

What conversion method are you using?

I would rather use the error mechanism of your conversion method, no matter if this is an exception or an return code.

N.B. you should use `inputString.empty()`, it's faster.

Comment: I updated the code to show what is happening if there is a success/error if that is what you meant

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtod` or `sscanf("%*lf%n", &n)` and see how many characters it consumed from the input string. Just keep in mind that their idea of valid double representation might be different from yours. For example, they allow leading spaces and trailing anything. Some additional tweaking might be necessary to make your check more restrictive, if necessary.